# DataContractSerializer Best Practices?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

**Edit -- I'll try to make my question more to the point**

I am working with the DataContractSerializer.  I noticed that when I instance the serializer, I can specify the Namespace and the Name.  Is there any guidance out there (or maybe a best-practice) to describe when I might want to take control of the name and namespace, and what I might want to use for the values?

I was tempted to use the namespace and class name of the class that I am serializing deserializing.  Is that a good or bad practice?

Comment: What is your objective? If you want lots of control over output, XmlSerializer actually offers finer-grained control. DCS supports some additional/different scenarios, but offers less control.

Comment: @Marc I don't really need a lot of control (at least, I'm not worried about what the output looks like).  I am concerned about forward compatibility (shoudl be able to deserialize if my assembly version changes, or if I add members to the contract (will not remove/rename))  This is to save some task execution parameters that will go into a queue, or saved to a table for scheduled execution.  I was interested in DCS because it works with Silverlight, seems to have the version safety that I need, and is WCF-friendly, if I wanted to use it in a service operation.  What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataContractSerialializer is a contract-based serializer, so forwards compatibility shouldn't  a huge problem as long as you are adding - and if you do want to rename, you can hide that by adding the old name via attributes. As such, I would say "keep it simple" - trying to get clever is the cause of many bugs.

Re "What do you think?" (comments) - I think I'd rather use protobuf-net, but I'm somewhat biased :p

Comment: You know -- I almost mentioned something about protobuf -- and I actually might end up using it <g>